# Verifying an inequality using Elementary Calculus

Tags: real-analysis

**Exercise:**

> Let $1\leq p < \infty$.
>   Use elementary calculus to show that $|t - s|^{p} \leq |t^{p} - s^{p}| \leq p|t-s|(s + t)^{p-1}$ for all $s,t\geq 0$.

---

**Progress:**

The problem can be reduced to the case where $t = 1$.

Indeed, if the above holds for all $s\geq 0$ when $t = 1$, then for general $s,t\geq 0$, we have

\begin{align}
|t - s|^{p} &= |t|^{p}\cdot \left|1 - \frac{s}{t}\right|^{p}\\
            &\leq |t|^{p}\cdot \left|1 - \left(\frac{s}{t}\right)^{p}\right|\\
            &= |t^{p} - s^{p}|
\end{align}

and the other half follows similarly.

---

**Where I am stuck:**

Let $t = 1$ and let $s < 1$.  Then the desired inequality becomes

$$(1 - s)^{p} \leq (1 - s^{p}) \leq p(1-s)(s + 1)^{p-1}$$

For now I'm just trying to show the first half.  But everything I have tried goes nowhere.  The wording of the problem suggest to me that convexity may be used somewhere to connect the inequality with the second derivative of some cleverly chosen function.  But I can't seem to find the trick.

Any hints would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the first inequality:

If either $t=0$ or $s=0$ then the inequality is clear. Thus, we may assume $t>0$ and $s>0$. By your observation it suffices to demonstrate the case when $t=1$ and $s<1$ by using symmetry of the absolute value and then dividing the the larger of the $s$ and $t$. Thus, it suffices to show:

$(1-s)^{p}\le1-s^{p}$ where absolute values have been removed due to the hypothesis.

Define $f(s)=(1-s)^{p}-s^{p}$ for $s\in(0,1)$. Then $f'(s)=-p(1-s)^{p-1}-ps^{p-1}=-p((1-s)^{p-1}+s^{p-1})$.

In the region of definition the derivative is $-p$ multiplied by a positive number. Thus, for all $s$ in the region defined $f$ is a decreasing function. Thus,

$f(s)\le\sup_{s\in(0,1)}f(s)\le1$ which is what we want.

For the second inequality:

$|t^{p}-s^{p}|=\lvert\int_{s}^{t}pu^{p-1}du \rvert\le\lvert\int_{s}^{t}1du\rvert\, p(s+t)^{p-1}=p\lvert t-s\rvert(s+t)^{p-1}$

Comment: Thank you very much!! Sorry for taking so long to reply!

Comment: You're welcome. No problem.

Answer (score 1):

Let 
$f(s) 
= (1-s^p)-(1-s)^p
$.
You want to show that
$f(s) \ge 0$.

If $p = 1$
then
$f(s)$ is identically zero,
so we can assume that
$p > 1$.

$f(0) = f(1) = 0$
and
$f(\frac12)
= 1-2(\frac12)^p
> 0
$
since $p > 1$.

$f'(s)
= -ps^{p-1}+p(1-s)^{p-1}
=p((1-s)^{p-1}-s^{p-1})
$.

If
$0 \le s \le \frac12$,
$f'(s) \ge 0$
since
$1-s \ge s$ in that range.

Similarly, if
$\frac12 \le s \le 1$,
$f'(s) \le 0$
since
$1-s \le s$ in that range.

Therefore
$f(s)$
increases from $0$ to $\frac12$
and decreases from
$\frac12$ to $1$.

Since $f(0) = f(1) = 0$
and
$f(\frac12)
> 0
$
since 
$p \ge 1$,
$f(s) \ge 0$
as desired.

Comment: Thanks!  Sorry for slow response!